# How to retrieve list of Points/coordinates from Mapbox rendered feature

Tags: android, mapbox

I have a `map` which renders objects from `GeoJson` file. I am trying to retrieve all the `points` and names from all the objects and save them to an array list so I can use them with a `searchBar.`

So far, I can retrieve all the names but have no idea how to retrieve the `coordinates.` I understand `mapBox` has a `feature.geometry` object but how do I use it to retrieve all coordinates from feature rendered on the map?

```
public ArrayList<Double> longitude;
    public ArrayList<Double> latitude;


    @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            SearchActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, style -> {
                mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(SearchActivity.this);
                addGeoJsonSourceToMap(style);
    // Create FillLayer with GeoJSON source and add the FillLayer to the map
                style.addLayer(new FillLayer(geoJsonLayerId, geoJsonSourceId)
                        .withProperties(fillOpacity(0.5f)));
                        GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs(geoJsonSourceId);
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    if (source != null){

  List<Feature> features = source.querySourceFeatures(Expression.all());
//fetch all points
                    FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(features);
                    List<Point> pointList = TurfMeta.coordAll(featureCollection, true);
                    for (Point singlePoint : pointList) {
                        List<Double> coordinateListForSinglePoint = singlePoint.coordinates();
                        Double lng = coordinateListForSinglePoint.get(0);
                        Double lat = coordinateListForSinglePoint.get(1);
                        longitude.add(lng);
                        latitude.add(lat);
                        for (int i  = 0; i < features.size(); i++){
                            Feature feature = features.get(i);
                            Log.d(TAG, feature.toString());
    // Ensure the feature has properties defined
                            if (feature.properties() != null) {
                                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry :  feature.properties().entrySet()) {
    // Log all the properties
                                    if (entry.getKey().equals("name")) {
                                        if (!arrayList2.contains(entry.getValue().toString())) {
                                            arrayList2.add(entry.getValue().toString().replace("\"", ""));
                                        }

                                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayList2);
                                        search.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        search.setThreshold(1);
                                        search.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, parent.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take advantage of https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/turf/ . Mapbox's port of http://turfjs.org/docs includes `TurfMeta.coordAll()`. This method will return a list of `Point` objects for a specific geometry (`Point`, `LineString`, etc.). You can also pass a `Feature` or `FeatureCollection` to the method.

`FeatureCollection` parameter: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-turf/src/main/java/com/mapbox/turf/TurfMeta.java#L264

`Feature` parameter: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-turf/src/main/java/com/mapbox/turf/TurfMeta.java#L245

```
          List<Feature> features = source.querySourceFeatures(Expression.all());

          FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(features);

          List<Point> pointList = TurfMeta.coordAll(featureCollection, true);

          for (Point singlePoint : pointList) {
            List<Double> coordinateListForSinglePoint = singlePoint.coordinates();
            Double longitude = coordinateListForSinglePoint.get(0);
            Double latitude = coordinateListForSinglePoint.get(1);
          }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to give the accurate position of buildings rendered on the map.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you say more? What's your end goal?

Comment: I have updated my code. The problem is that the points being retrieved are not accurate to what I have on my GeoJSON file

Comment: am meant to retrieve all names and points in a spinner such that once a name is clicked, it zooms to that point on the map.